# Is there a short proof that the Krull dimension of $k[x_1, \dots,x_n]$ is $n$ using dimension theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

It is well known that if $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ a noetherian local ring, then $\dim{A}$ is finite and
$$\dim{A}=\deg{\lambda_A}=\delta_A, $$
where $\lambda_A$ is the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial of $A$ and $\delta_A$ is the minimum number of elements in the system of parameters of $A$.

My question is: It is possible to do an easier proof, using the above theorem, of the fact that
$$\dim k[x_1,\dots, x_n] = n $$
when $k$ is a field?

Comment: See exercise 4.27 in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra book

Comment: It is true that if the maximal  ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated $n$ elements, then his height is also $n$?

Comment: In any Noetherian ring, the height of an ideal is always _at most_ the number of generators. In the polynomial ring over a field, there is an obvious maximal ideal which has height equal to the number of variables

Comment: That maximal ideal would be $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$?

Comment: Yes $\hspace{0cm}$